# Objective C : UITableView : cellForRowAtIndexPath being called in iPhone but fails in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` being called in iPhone but fails in iPad. Because I just started migrating my existing app for iPhone to universal, so at least for now I'm using the same `xib` file for the two environment. Any help would be appreciated, because it already spoiled my 2 working days.(Its not because of the "no of sections" or "rows in sections', tried with hard coded values).

Work Fine on iPhone Simulator, but not work on iPad Simulator :

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad{
             [super viewDidLoad];
             [mytable setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

              mytable.delegate = self;
              mytable.dataSource = self;
      }

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
       {
        return 1;
        }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    //never get called when device is iPad simulator.
  }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [tableData count];//tried with return 1;
}

-(void)LoadBindMenu{

     //this method is called from external code, its working, do not suspect pls
    //collection will be populated and reloading data

     [mytable reloadData];

 }
```

Comment: Did you properly Give the Datasource to that class?

Comment: @your wish : already mentioned that it works fine in iPhone, same code, same xib.

Comment: What about ipad's xib delegate,datasource? hav u set?

Comment: If its Okay then give link of your code, To see exact problem.

Comment: Give some code for solution

Comment: @Singh : sorry i don't understand u, can you elaborate it(Frame For TableView for iPad)..

Comment: @sudhi: first try to log in "numberOfRowsInSection" method that how many row this mehod will return. I am not sure but may be this method returns 0 rows i think

Comment: if you use only one xib for iPhone And iPad Then you have to set the Frame of your controls..... For ipad and for iphone

Comment: @ParvendraSingh You can do it manually in Xib without code!

Comment: @Singh : Where i can set the Frame, i'm afraid, never done before!!

Comment: @your wish : in "view did load" method {mytable.delegate = self;
    mytable.dataSource = self;} then method (- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section) return 1; then method (- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView) also returns 1;

Comment: @ParvendraSingh If your UI is not very much complex then you can use single xib by setting Autosizing according to your need in Auto Inspector.

Comment: @sudhi if You Don`t need to sections in your project then remove - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView) returns 1;   method.

Comment: last thing try to clean(window + shift + K) Xcode and reset your simulator then run your code. May it works if you didn`t make mistakes in your code.

Comment: @Bauch : i don't know how to explain my problem in a better, but i can clearly say that it is exactly what i've described in the question. i'm really stuck..(bcoz it works in iPhone but not called in iPad..oops)

Comment: @sudhi you make your app universal in project.?

Comment: @Singh : yeah, this is not the only Controller, there are many more, including UITableView, but in this case i couldn't figure it out..

Comment: @sudhi Do one thing please Use BreakPoint and check step by step what is the problem in real.then write your error here .......

Comment: "i can promise you everything is set correct". This made me cry a little. You severely lack information about your problem and lack code so we can make steps to reproduce. Fix this and we can help you fix your problem.

Comment: @Maximus : i've made that statement only bcoz its working fine in iPhone simulator

Comment: @Singh how we can use the help of breakpoints, becoz these delegate methods are invoked internally.

Comment: @sudhi Your app cresh on cellForRowAtIndexPath... ok just before this you use  numberOfRowInSection (i hope).. then Use a BreakPoint (Debugger) at numberOfRowInSection....

Comment: @Singh : already mentioned in the question i'm using hard coded values for now(returns 1;)

Comment: @sudhi oks no problem but you have to know that where your app is crash and why so you need to use Debugger pls do it for solution.

Comment: @sudhi This is the last solution for your problem... That create an another xib also for iPad. and create all the controls over it for iPad.

Comment: @Singh created another xib for iPad, now its WORKING, still i don't know what was the problem. Big thanks for your suggestion, otherwise i would have continued playing with the same files. thanks man.

Comment: Welcome @sudhi Actully you have to use debugger for know about the error.....

Answer (score 1):

Write In your Prifix.pch

```
      #define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
      #define IS_WIDESCREEN (fabs((double)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height -    (double)568) < DBL_EPSILON)
      #define IS_IPHONE (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]) || ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString: @"iPhone Simulator"]))
      #define IS_IPOD   ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]model] isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"])
      #define IS_IPOD_5 ((IS_IPOD) && IS_WIDESCREEN)
      #define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

And in your viewWillApper.......

```
         if(IS_IPAD)
            {

             tableView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024);

            }

          if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
            {

              if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
                {

                   tableView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,568);

                }
             else
               {
                  tableView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
               }
            }
```